# Sketchfab hide and show ID not clear

Tags: javascript

How do I get the sketchfab hide and show object ID? I'm confused and help would be greatly appreciated. I've searched in blender and stuff but I couldnt find it. Currently I'm doing

```
func hideshow() {
if (hiding == true) {
api.hide(myNode, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        window.console.log('Hid node', myNode); // 114
    }
});
} else {
api.show(myNode, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        window.console.log('Showed node', myNode); // 114
    }
});
}
}
```

but mynode isnt clear how you are supposed to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experience with the sketchfab API, and what you are attempting is quite simple. All you need to do is find the InstanceID of an object, found with getNodeMap, like so:

```
api.getNodeMap(function(err, nodes) {
    if (!err) {
        window.console.log(nodes); // [ ... ]
    }
});
```

You can find the Sketchfab documentation which will help you very much along your journey, [here](https://sketchfab.com/developers/viewer/functions#api-section-objects)

Comment: ok but how do I see the instance ID

Comment: To see the instance ID in your HTML document on chrome, or other browsers, press F12 and go to console. You will see a console print there, look for something in the list that says "Exampleobject", click it, and in the dropdown you will see the instance ID and other useful things. Exampleobject will be replaced with whatever object you are using.